# Unable to click element

Tags: javascript, selenium, webdriver, appium

I'm using appium and have created a framework for automation. Having inspected an element using Appium inspector, I'm now trying to click the element (in the DOM but not in the field of view of device screen) using `waitForElementByName`. In the logs, I see that the element gets found and the element number is returned, however, the `.click()` fails and the automation exits.

If I manually scroll to get the element in the field of view, then the `.click()` works.

Is there any solution to this problem? I've already tried `wd.asserters.isDisplayed`, but doesn't work!

Comment: What error(s) are you getting?

Comment: No error in particular. That's the weird part. Here's what the log says:

RESPONSE waitForElementByXPath("//UIAButton[@name=‘<element>']",16000){"ELEMENT":"7"}
EVENT:COMMAND: CALLelement.click()
EVENT:HTTP   : POST/session/:sessionID/element/7/click

or

RESPONSE waitForElementByName(“<name>",16000) {"ELEMENT":"7"}
EVENT:COMMAND: CALLelement.click()
EVENT:HTTP   : POST/session/:sessionID/element/7/click

And then I get the error that script failed. If I scroll to get the element in screen field of view, the click works fine and the framework moves to clicking the next element in sequence then.

Comment: its ver hard to say anything by just looking at your question. Please do mention logs and your code in your question.

Answer (score 1):

So the problem you are facing is actually something that people who use Instruments face (I am assuming this based on the UIAButton in your comments). Your automation is finding the element because in terms of the xml tree of the view layout it exists and has been found. However being found in the layout and visible on the screen are not the same thing.

To solve this you need to check the isVisible property of the element. If `isVisible == false`, then you should `scrollToVisible`(this is the name of a method specific to iOS UIA) and then .click() Attempting to .click() on an element that is not visible on the screen is not possible.